# charts.js not updating after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

I'm a complete newb with js and jquery but have muddled my way through getting a chart to properly display using Flask and an Ajax request. Where I'm having a problem is getting the charts data to refresh. I can get the chart to display just fine if I create it as a new chart as shown in the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getdata = $.post('/charts');
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart

getdata.done(function(results){

    var chartData = {
    labels: results['month'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Debits',
      data: results['debit'],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
    }, {
      label: 'Credits',
      data: results['credit'],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
    }, {
      label: 'Balance',
      data: results['balance'],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(50,110,0,0.4)"
    }]
  }

    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'line', data: chartData});
});

$("form :input").change(function() {
    year = $(this).val();
    console.log(year)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/data",
        data: {'year':year},

        success: function(results){
            var updatedData = {
             labels : results['month'],

             datasets : [{
                  label: 'Debits',
                  data: results['debit'],
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                    }, {
                  label: 'Credits',
                  data: results['credit'],
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }, {
                      label: 'Balance',
                      data: results['balance'],
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(50,110,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                    }
            myChart= new Chart(ctx, {type: 'line', data: updatedData});
        }
    });
});

});
```

But if I change the last line to

```
myChart.update(updatedData)
```

nothing happens, I don't get any errors, the chart doesn't update. Nothing. The strange thing is that I know the myChart is global because I don't have to create it again after the Ajax request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of charts.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart), you first need to change data and then call update (arguments for update function are not the data, but duration etc.):

.update(duration, lazy)

Triggers an update of the chart. This can be safely called after replacing the entire data object. This will update all scales, legends, and then re-render the chart.

```
// duration is the time for the animation of the redraw in milliseconds
// lazy is a boolean. if true, the animation can be interrupted by other animations
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 50; // Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
myLineChart.update(); // Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
```

So in your case:

```
myChart.data = updatedData;
myChart.update();
```